# NullReferenceException and view model navigation properties

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, view, viewmodel

I am struggling to find a way to deal with null values in my view model.  Some of these values are nested or navigation objects within my model.  How do I keep my view from throwing a null reference error without introducing logic into the view?  This seems easy but it is the end of the day.

I have a view model with some navigation properties like so:

ViewModel.cs

```
public class ViewModel
{
  public ViewModel () {}
  public ViewModel (Contact contact, IDemographicService demographicService)
         : this()
  {
    Id = contact.Id;
    Name = contact.Name;
    EthnicityId = contact.EthnicityId;
    if(EthnicityId > 0 || EthnicityId != null)
       Ethnicity = deomographicService.GetEthnicityById((int)contact.EthnicityId);
  }
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public int? EthnicityId {get;set;}
  public Ethnicity Ethnicity {get;set;}
}
```

I'll skip the controller because that is not the focus of my question.  (I know that the logic can go in the controller but I chose to put it in the ViewModel).

MyView.cshtml

```
@model ViewModel
<ul>
<li>@Model.Name</li>
<li>@Model.Ethnicity.Name</>//This is the null reference.
</ul>
```

I guess I could define only a "EthnicityName" string (and if null return null) instead of an entire object but there are instances where I need more than one property from the Ethnicity object.  This eliminates Ethnicity, whether it is in the view model, controller, or view. In short, what do I do about null.null?  Stumped.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hardly think it's a terrible thing to add "logic" for understanding null values. Such logic is part of the underlying .NET object model; it's not business logic.

Still, you can add one property to the model for each property of the `Ethnicity` type that you want visible in the model:

```
public Ethnicity Ethnicity {get;set;}
public string EthnicityName {
    get {return Ethnicity == null ? String.Empty : Ethnicity.Name;}
    set {if (Ethnicity != null) {Ethnicity.Name = value;}}
}
public int EthnicityCode {
    get {return Ethnicity == null ? 0 : Ethnicity.Code;}
    set {if (Ethnicity != null) {Ethnicity.Code = value;}}
}
```

Then the view has no work to do at all.

Note that I think that this sort of delegation is ok, as opposed to formatting. I would never add a property to the model that was only for the purpose of formatting.

Comment: Thanks John.  Your answer was along the lines of what I thought I would have to do.  Although my example is fairly simplistic, my project encompasses other 'nested' objects that have large numbers of properties where defining every property defeats the purpose of a view model.  In this type of instance would an "else" statement that creates an empty object be verboten? i.e. else LargeObject = new LargeObject(); This way my view that has @Model.LargeObject.Property won't throw a null. I hate nulls, but I am forced to deal with them.

Comment: p.s. I meant logic in the view

Comment: @name: I'm not an MVC expert, though I've got the general idea in terms of separation of concerns. I don't think this constitutes a separate concern. I would ask the question of _why_ I have those null values - what's the semanatics? What do they represent to the model?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a class design problem, not a View/Model problem. You have a class that declares that it will provide an Ethnicity as part of its immutable state upon initialization. However, when you actually create the object you aren't making that guarantee for the class's consumers. I think that @John Saunders solution is viable, but I would be more willing to instantiate a Default Ethnicity instance as a static member on the Ethnicity type and return that. The Name property of that default would return a language appropriate answer for "None Supplied" or something like that.

Comment: Ritch I get what your saying and it is something I considered but the reality of my project (my example was simple for posting) is that I have large object graphs that unfortunately CAN be null. Health care claims meets grant writer and decides his brother public health pilot-project is better looking.

Comment: Making a distinction between null and Empty is a behavior of the model.

Comment: But based on my example Ethnicity is not empty it's null.  I can't control if the user did not select a ethnicity.  Therefore Ethnicity.Name == null.null.  John's answer above solves this problem unless you have a large object with many properties.

Comment: It does solve it, but it creates a dependency in the ViewModel for every property in the Ethnicity class. Imagine if you had 50, or 100 properties to forward in that mannor. What if you change the type of one of the Properties. That kind of coupling is uncessary and makes things fragile.  I'd add an example, but you seem happy with @John's response, so I'll let it go.

Comment: I guess I am not doing a good job of explaining myself.  Your last comment describes exactly my real predicament.  I agree 100% with what you are saying about 50 or 100 properties.  I guess my question is: If Ethnicity had 50 properties that may or may not be viewed (@Model.Ethnicity.Property1, etc.) in the view?  Then would a if/else statement that creates an empty Ethnicity object to satisfy the view be bad practice?  That is the only solution I can think of sans John's answer and the dependencies you described.

Comment: No, the if/else is not bad practice. when constructing the VM, if the read in ethnicity is null assign the VM's Ethnicity property to Ethnicity.Empty is the solution that I am recommending.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in implementing the `IDataErrorInfo` interface on your `ViewModel` therefore implementing validation logic there instead of right on the properties getter/setters.